# How do I create a seamless transition from phonegap splash screen?

Tags: screen, cordova, splash-screen

I'm trying to achieve the following user experience for my phonegap iOS splash screen:

1. User launches app and sees custom splash screen image of company logo
2. When app is loaded, logo animates upwards to reveal first screen in the app.

If you get a chance try the free "ex fm" iPhone app - they've done exactly what I'm talking about.

Currently, I'm able to dismiss the phonegap splash screen using their API, but this makes the logo disappear altogether. How can I achieve the animate up effect?

One solution I tried was replicating the splash screen in the html document. So after the phonegap splash goes away, the same image appears which gives the illusion that it never went away in the first place. At this point i have control of the DOM and use JavaScript to animate the logo upwards..

Problem is there is always a slight flicker or jitter just when the phonegap splash screen disappears and the html image appears.

What is the best practice solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

im just about to try something similar. The approach im going to take to get over the flicker is using the phonegap FadeSplashScreen option in config.xml (only available in the latest couple of versions of phonegap)  this seems to eliminate the flicker